# Understanding Maps and slot

Tags: list-manipulation, random, fractals

Going through some old code I found this line:

```
SampleSierpinskiCarpet[n_] := 
 Module[{digitpairs = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 
  0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}}, 
  Map[N[#.(1/3^Range[26])] &, 
   Transpose[RandomChoice[digitpairs, {n, 26}], {1, 3, 2}], {2}]]
```

Could someone explain exactly whats going on here? There is a lot of syntax to unpack, and no extra comments to go along with it.

When plotted it produces a [Sierpiński Carpet](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiCarpet.html):

```
S = SampleSierpinskiCarpet[100000];
V = SimilarFunction[100000];
Row[ListPlot[#, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], AspectRatio -> 1, 
ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {S, V}]
```

Yields:
[image]

edit:
Thanks for the help everyone: The similar function looks like this

```
SampleViksecFractal[n_] :=
Module[{digitpairs = {{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}}}, 
Map[N[#.(1/3^Range[26])] &, 
Transpose[RandomChoice[digitpairs, {n, 26}], {1, 3, 2}], {2}]]
```

Comment: Here's the rough idea: Essentially, each point of the carpet is described by a list of offsets (an element of `digitcharacters`). You choose `26` offsets, each for a subsequent level of the fractal, which are then multiplied by `1/3^n`, where `n` is the level. For the rest, try to evaluate parts of the expression one by one to see how the output changes as include more and more of the original code

Comment: Do you have the definition of `SimilarFunction` as well?

Comment: This is basically a chaos game procedure for the Sierpinski carpet.